# How do I free the memory allocated in my RPC server?

Tags: rpc, sunrpc

I have an RPC server that transfers a large amount of variable length data to the client.  The .x file looks something like this

```
struct file
{
    opaque data<>
};
```

In the server routine, I have

```
struct file *transfer_1_svc(...)
{
    struct file;

    file.data.data_val = malloc(...);

    return &file;
}
```

My question is who frees the data allocated in the server routine?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your server code. If you use rpcgen to produce server stub, then you can use **xdr_free** function which will free the result. Check SunRPC developer guide for details: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-1435/rpcgenpguide-21470/index.html